# Simple hide/show nav broken when switch jQuery libs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Greeting fellow StackOverflow-ians. I'm in a bit of a pickle and am hoping some of you can help, if not at least point me in the right direction.

I have simple nested UL navigation, and am using jQuery to hide/show sub-menus on click, mouse-over, or mouse-out. Works fine.

**Here's the problem:** I built it referencing jQuery 1.8.3, but it does function at all on pages still referencing jQuery 1.7.1. (And I cannot just update the lib on those pages.)

Are there simple changes I can make to my syntax, or do I need to start from scratch?

Here's the code I'm using:

**HTML**
(I inherited this code, and it cannot be changed.)

```
<ul class="mainNav">
<li><span>Categories</span>
    <ul class="subNav">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2 yay!</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span>Resources</span>
    <ul class="subNav">
        <li><a href="#">more links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">many much links</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

$(".mainNav").on('click mouseenter  mouseleave', '> li', function() {
    if (!($(this).find('.subNav').hasClass('showNav'))) {
        $('.showNav').removeClass('showNav');
        $(this).find('.subNav').addClass('showNav');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.subNav').removeClass('showNav');
    }
});
});
```

[See it in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmlmonkey/j9ntt/1/)

Comment: looks like the problem is with the dynamic selector `'> li'`

Comment: do you want to preserve the event delegation model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the dynamic element selector, in 1.7 it does not seems to like the `>` at the start of the selector.

So try

```
$(function () {

    $(".mainNav").on('click mouseenter  mouseleave', 'li:has(ul.subNav)', function () {
        if (!($(this).find('.subNav').hasClass('showNav'))) {
            $('.showNav').removeClass('showNav');
            $(this).find('.subNav').addClass('showNav');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.subNav').removeClass('showNav');
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bEX6s/)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the selector from:

```
$(".mainNav").on('click mouseenter  mouseleave', '> li', function() {
```

To:

```
$(".mainNav > li").on('click mouseenter  mouseleave', function() {
```

And it should work..

[Here's your fiddle modified](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ntt/4/)

Please notice that by this you lose the event binding for dynamically added li's.. but if your list is static then this shall be fine..

Comment: Thanks for the help! (I wish you could mark more than one answer as 'accepted' -- especially when there are similar answers.)
:)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the ".on" functionality did not exist in earlier versions. ".live" is being deprecated but should still function in both versions.  It might also be that the "> li" needs to be part of the main selector. That part looks a little off to me as well.

Comment: The on exists starting from 1.7 and he wants 1.7

Comment: Indeed -- "> li" was definitely my issue. I was worried I might not get any answers on a Saturday - but I'm glad you guys are around. :)